# Lotus Notes - Mark a document line (Highlight the line in a different color)

Tags: java, email, export, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a small program that will export a selected lotus notes mail document.
I would like to mark a successfully exported line in a different color (or mark it in some manner so as to distinguish exported lines)

There is a flag concept in the Notes client but it seems it is associated with followups etc. As such I would prefer not to user the flagging mechanism.

Is there any other way to mark a given mail line?

Answer (score 4):

Use the column option "Use value as color".

1. Set a flag (=item) in your documents which were exported, e.g.

   `doc.replaceItemValue("Exported", "exported")`
2. Create a new column with options set "Use value as color" and "Hide column" and the formula

   `@If(Exported != ""; 0:0:0:255:255:255; "")`

The exported documents would be highlighted with white text on black background (0:0:0:255:255:255):
[image]

Look [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21188772) for more information.